# Preselect items in h:selectManyCheckbox

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

How do I preselect the elements in a `h:selectManyCheckbox` component? I've searched through the properties of the `f:selectItem` tag but not yet have found how to pre-select this item (i.e. it is ticked already when the site is called).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `value` attribute of `h:selectManyCheckbox` can accept an array of string from the managed bean. You can directly set the default values to this array when the managed bean is initialized.

For example , in the view :

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{MBean.choice}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="A" itemLabel="Choice A" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="B" itemLabel="Choice B" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="C" itemLabel="Choice C"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="D" itemLabel="Choice D" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Then in the MBean :

```
public class MBean{

    //Preselect the "Choice A" and "Choice C" 
    private String[] choice= {"A","C"};

    //Getter and setter of choice

}
```

Comment: `List<T>` is also supported by the way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was looking for something like a `SELECTED` property, but sure enough, this is the way to achieve this. I was not seeing the forest, blinded by all the trees.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your backing list or array objects that return true when comparing equals to the value of the SelectItems you want to preselect.