# JSF: Default selection of all values in <h:selectManyListbox/>

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I am working in **jsf 2.0**. From **rich:popup** based on user selection i am adding values into **h:selectManyListbox** using AJAX and then i re-render the enclosing **outputPanel** to display values from binding list. I am able to do this successfully. Now i want that all the values present in the **selectedManyListbox**    should be selected by default so that user is not suppose to select it again.

*code for selectManyListBox :*

```
    <a4j:outputPanel id="groupTablePanel">
                    <h:selectManyListbox size="3" style="width:190px; height:100px;"
                        id="table" value="#{userCreateBean.selectedGroups}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{userCreateBean.assignedGroups}"></f:selectItems>
                    </h:selectManyListbox>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
```

I explored the documentation of same, i even tried writing my own javascript code. ***Looking into firebug, i am not able to see the associated class for selected values in selectManyListbox***. Also the onChange event of same gets executed only when we manually make any change in same, or click on it. So i would like to know **which event will be appropriate to work with this kind of requirement**?
Please guide me how i can achieve this functionality.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was thinking too much about it, in the end it turned out to be very easy. this javascript method helped me solve same.                     `function defaultUsersSelect(id){                                         var select = document.getElementById(id);
 for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++){
 select.options[i].setAttribute("selected","selected");
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking too much about it, in the end it turned out to be very easy. this javascript method helped me solve same.

```
function defaultUsersSelect(id){  
  var select = document.getElementById(id);
  for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++){
   select.options[i].setAttribute("selected","selected");
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately you failed to do it the proper way, which is to simply populate the selectedGroups list with all the values you want selected by default while initializing the backing bean. You've now introduced a manual javascript hack to work around that.

Comment: @Gimby Yes you are correct, could you please suggest me better solution. Thanks.

Comment: You are asking "give me a better solution" to my comment containing a better solution. What you really want is code. I'm not going to spend time cooking up something which has been shown hundreds of times already, a simple google for "javaserver faces selectManyListBox preselect" turned up this existing question for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650327/preselect-items-in-hselectmanycheckbox

Comment: @Gimby - Comment shows how good gentleman you are. I never asked for any code. And moreover you didn't even understood my question. But i respect your input, thank you for spending time reading my question.